# MySQL LEFT JOIN not returning NULL for missing rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm probably messing it up. But I have a WordPress system where I am trying to build an export of specific user data in MySQL. 
I am expecting metadata to return `NULL` if the row doesn't exist, but instead it seems like it's acting like a limit. If any of the metadata doesn't exist the entire user is omitted.

```
SELECT
  users.ID,
  users.user_email,
  _first.meta_value as firstName,
  _second.meta_value as lastName,
  users.display_name,
  _gender.meta_value as gender,
  _age.meta_value as age,
  _nationality.meta_value as nationality

FROM kp_users

LEFT JOIN usermeta as _first ON kp_users.id = _first.user_id
LEFT JOIN usermeta as _second ON kp_users.id = _second.user_id
LEFT JOIN usermeta as _gender ON kp_users.id = _gender.user_id
LEFT JOIN usermeta as _age ON kp_users.id = _age.user_id
LEFT JOIN usermeta as _nationality ON kp_users.id = _nationality.user_id

WHERE
  _first.meta_key = 'first_name' AND
  _second.meta_key = 'last_name' AND
  _gender.meta_key = '_user_demographics_gender' AND
  _age.meta_key = '_user_demographics_age' AND
  _nationality.meta_key = '_user_demographics_nationality'
```

So, for metadata rows where, say, the `_user_demographics_age` row doesn't exist the entire user is omitted from the final set of results, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why MySQL's LEFT JOIN is returning "NULL" records when with WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589529/why-mysqls-left-join-is-returning-null-records-when-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your others conditions in ON clause instead of Where Clause like below -

```
SELECT
  users.ID,
  users.user_email,
  _first.meta_value as firstName,
  _second.meta_value as lastName,
  users.display_name,
  _gender.meta_value as gender,
  _age.meta_value as age,
  _nationality.meta_value as nationality

FROM kp_users

LEFT JOIN usermeta as _first ON kp_users.id = _first.user_id and _first.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN usermeta as _second ON kp_users.id = _second.user_id and _second.meta_key = 'last_name'
LEFT JOIN usermeta as _gender ON kp_users.id = _gender.user_id and _gender.meta_key = '_user_demographics_gender'
LEFT JOIN usermeta as _age ON kp_users.id = _age.user_id and _age.meta_key = '_user_demographics_age'
LEFT JOIN usermeta as _nationality ON kp_users.id = _nationality.user_id and _nationality.meta_key = '_user_demographics_nationality'
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your left join tables "where" conditions to the relative "on" conditions. At the moment your getting your null fields, but then your where condition is filtering them out because _first.meta_key is null and this doesn't equal 'firsst_name,

Answer (score 0):

Move all your filters from `where` to `left join`:

`LEFT JOIN usermeta as _first ON kp_users.id = _first.user_id and _first.meta_key = 'first_name'
LEFT JOIN usermeta as _second ON kp_users.id = _second.user_id and _second.meta_key = 'last_name'
-- etc.`

MySQL optimizer changes `left join` to `join`, if left-joined table has conditions in `where` part of query (that's an approximation, there are additional rules).